# vector memory exhausted (limit reached?)

Tags: r, memory, vector

I am using Rstudio 2022.02.0 Build 443 and macOS Catalina version 10.15.7. I am working on dataset dim= 70856886 observation. I get error which is:

> vector memory exhausted (limit reached?)

and I could not solve this problem at all.

The error that get while I was trying to clean my data and imputing my dataset.

The sizes of my two objects are dim(df)=(70856886 15) and dim(d_condition)= (354 6) they have common factor which is subject and the range of subject is from 845 to 1246.

- My computer RAM: 16 GB 2400 MHz DDR4
- My processor: 2.6 GHz 6-Core Intel Core i7
- My Mac: macOS Monterey, version 12.3

Comment: You're run out of RAM basically.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Yeah, if you're trying to perform a merge on a 70M+ row data frame I'm not surprised you're having RAM issues - that thing is huge.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Unfortunately, I think the odds of a satisfying answer to your question are pretty small, but it could happen.  There are a variety of ways you can improve your question to increase your chances of getting useful responses. (1) let us know the sizes of the two objects you're trying to merge (`dim(df); dim(d_condition)`); (2) let us know how much RAM you have; (3) edit your question to include the information in a **text format** (i.e., cut-and-paste text from your RStudio session, rather than showing us a photo or screen capture)